# Migrated question from meta to main allows me to upvote same comment twice

Tags: support, bug

Friends, I noticed something "interesting" today. The question

[How to include a long underscore before the \question command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78894)

was originally posted in our meta site. Andrew wrote a comment in the question, and I upvoted his comment (I also voted the question for closing/migration).

Now the question is migrated to our main site, and curiously, Andrew's comment has the "great comment counter" in it, but no flag (the triangle) indicating that I already upvoted it. In other words, I can upvote it twice!

[image: Printscreen]

And I did, for testing purposes:

[image: Printscreen]

Believe it or not, those two votes are mine. I think migrated questions should keep their references. I know meta and main behave differently, but it was really "funny" to see that I could upvote stuff more than one time.

Is this a desired behaviour?

**Note:** I'm adding the [bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) tag, but again, I don't know if this is a desired behaviour or not.

Comment: Seems to be a corollary to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87031/reset-votes-on-migrated-questions

Comment: Well of course, it's a meta comment. :)

Comment: The same applies to migrated questions (and thus presumably posts in general): I just upvoted http://superuser.com/questions/488319/generate-pdf-that-is-not-editable on [SU], even though I had already upvoted http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75311/generate-pdf-that-is-not-editable?noredirect=1 (10k only) on [tex.se].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect it should be classed as "It probably shouldn't work like that but the hassle in fixing it vastly outweighs the importance of doing so."

Sadly, I also deleted that comment as it was no longer relevant.  The 2 votes made me pause since perhaps, I felt, I shouldn't delete something that *two* people thought was a "Great Comment".  But now that I learn that one of them was a duck I don't feel so bad.

(More seriously, I deleted it as it was no longer relevant as it was just suggesting to the questioner that they repost on the main site.)

Comment: I share the same thought, Andrew. `:)` Since meta/main are different contexts, maybe it's ok to accept this behaviour. Anyway, I found it an amusing situation. `:)`

Comment: +1 for duckduck